# Android Socket Not Playing Nice

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

As Title.

Here is code:

```
InputStream is = tcp.getInputStream();
            int bytesRead = 0;
            do{
                byte[] byteIn = new byte[16* 1024];
                bytesRead = is.read(byteIn, 0, 16*1024);
                pStore.storeData(byteIn, 1024); 
                processMessage(pStore.readAll());
                pStore.clear();             
            }while(bytesRead>0);
```

Problem I have is that it never reaches the end of the while loop. Any suggestions would be muchly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javadoc to `InputStream.read()` says:

> This method blocks until input data is
>   available

Which is what you may be seeing.

You may test with `InputStream.available()` if there is any data to be read first.

Comment: No, it retrieves the Data, but it doesn't ever leave the loop. It passes through the loop, i.e, it doesn't hang on that statement in the debugger, but it seems to never reach the end of the Stream. It's just annoying really since thats the way i know your supposed to do it...

Comment: It can't know it has reached the end of the stream, because when it does the blocking call that you hope would discover this will not return until there is data, at which point it's no longer going to indicate that it is at the end because it no longer was.  The only way it will stop is in response to an error, perhaps (eventually) loss of connection.

Comment: Wait...Reads at most length bytes from this stream and stores them in the byte array b starting at offset.
Parameters

buffer the byte array in which to store the bytes read.
offset the initial position in buffer to store the bytes read from this stream.
length the maximum number of bytes to store in b.
Returns

the number of bytes actually read or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached.
Throws

IndexOutOfBoundsException if offset < 0 or length < 0, or if offset + length is greater than the length of b.
IOException if the stream is closed or another IOException occurs.

This is from API

Comment: @Taffy: InputStream can be used with various input sources. For disks based files, you always know in advance how big the file is and if it is e.g. 10 bytes long and you request 20 bytes, your assumption yields true. For networking, this is different. If the remote does not forcibly close the connection, you will never know in advance if it will send more bytes.